# Application redirects to "cart" page after removing "Delivery" Step in Spree 2.0.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I have deleted "Delivery" step from Spree 2.0.0 checkout process. Now when i fill address fields and Continue my application redirects me to "Cart" displaying my cart is empty even though i have added items to cart. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution it is a known issue. Check it on github

https://github.com/huoxito/spree/commit/505e256967f1ae79fee61e2dc2eca8ad91cdd9cf

Here is the solution.

Step 1: Override Spree checkout_controller "before_payment" method by creating a decorator file in app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller_decorator.rb

Srep 2: Paste following code in it.

```
Spree::CheckoutController.class_eval do
  def before_payment
  if @order.checkout_steps.include? "delivery"
  packages = @order.shipments.map { |s| s.to_package }
  @differentiator = Spree::Stock::Differentiator.new(@order, packages)
  @differentiator.missing.each do |variant, quantity|
  @order.contents.remove(variant, quantity)
  end
end
end
end
```

Thanks to Spree community.